# getting error in jboss migration

Tags: jboss, wildfly

2017-04-27 14:40:36,574 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."EARApplication.ear"."WebApplication1.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EARApplication.ear"."WebApplication1.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "WebApplication1.war" of deployment "EARApplication.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

2017-04-27 14:40:36,636 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = EARApplication.ear_org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver_10_2
2017-04-27 14:40:36,609 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."EARApplication.ear"."WebApplication2.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EARApplication.ear"."WebApplication2.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "WebApplication2.war" of deployment "EARApplication.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

Comment: It looks like you have a library in your application at a newer version than a copy in the application server so you end up with a mix of classes visible to your application. As you notice this is a bad thing. You could use a single classloader to get around this issue. You should place appropriate spring libraries